# Warning on converting a non-bare repo to bare repo: "appear to have cloned an empty repository"

Tags: git

I am converting my existing non-bare repo to bare repo using the following command:

```
git clone --bare -l non_bare_repo new_bare_repo
```

However, I get a warning saying

> You appear to have cloned an empty repository

Why this is happening, any idea?

Comment: So, is `non_bare_repo` actually empty?!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the hidden `.git` folder and edit `config` file:

```
[core]
    bare = true
```

Then remove any local copy files and you will have the bare repository.

Comment: I'm not clear how this addresses the original question. (Which was "why is this happening?").   Why was it happening? :)

Comment: @GreenAsJade: my method just won't have this issue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This warning happens when you clone an empty repository: a repository with no commits.

It is only a warning, of course: that means the outcome might be OK for you.

Git warns you about this, because generally you would be cloning a repo to get and work on its content.  So it seems like it might be a mistake - something to warn you about - that you are cloning an empty repo.

Note that when you clone a repo with no commits, you do *not* get any working files that were in the source repo.

So in your case, the working files in your non-bare repo would not have been copied over to the bare repo (obviously, because bare repos can't have working files).

This means that a possibly-more logical way of doing what you did was

```
  git init --bare new-bare-repo
```

Doing it this way avoids implying that you achieved anything other than making an empty bare repo.